# BLE advertising channel

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know  how to see in which channel our BLE device is advertising its data. Can we configure (change) on our own or is it chosen randomly?

I know this much there are three channels allocated for advertising BLE data.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that's handled on a lower level than you have access to via software.

Comment: I have been debugging the BlueZ stack but I am not able to find in which function channel is being allocated. Can you point me out the function ?

Comment: Again, I'm pretty sure the advertising channels are on the hardware end and abstracted away before getting to the software.  In Bluez there's likely no concept of advertising channels.

Comment: Maybe it's be better if you said what you were trying to do because you're probably going about it the wrong way if you're trying to separate advertising channels.

Comment: Is it the same case with the data channels as well??

Comment: I need to know in which channel BLE device is advertising its data and print it.But now as you have said its not possible..need to find out the other way :(  one more thing then is this same with RSSI also? Can we get other device's RSSI level and print it?

Comment: But _why_ do you need to get the channel and print it?

Comment: All the physical data channels are abstracted away too.  The whole point to multiple physical channels is to avoid interference from multiple devices and it automatically changes channels as necessary.  As for RSSI, that value can either be requested explicitly or it's also available as part of the advertising packets.

Comment: We are collecting probes for nearby BLE devices the format includes the MAC Address of Device, RSSI strength,Channel and time stamp.Plus we were also designing GUI for the same ,and requirment was to display the channel in which its advertising,so any other way u can suggest?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea...  Best source of information is the Bluetooth specs:  https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `chan_map` using the `le_set_advertising_parameters` structure to advertise on the particular channel

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know about the channel over which advertising data is transmitted you can create a packet sniffer for yourself...

The hex file for that can be found in 
\program files\Texas Instruments\SmartRF Tools\Packet Sniffer\bin\general\firmware\sniffer_fw_cc2540_usb.hex

For everything about packet sniffer refer

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/BLE_sniffer_guide

You can come to know about everything your BLE device is transmitting using packet sniffer.There are dozens of filters and everything you can configure in packet sniffer and visualize just the data you want.The transmitting channels are also described and from that you can know about the channel over which your advertising data is being transmitted...

The transmitting of advertising data is handeled over channel 37, 38 and 39 at frequencies 2.402, 2.426 and 2.480 Ghz respectively.This is actually handled by physical layer and as of I know you cant configure it...